# Pandas MultiIndex slicing without sorting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, multi-index

Given a DataFrame with multi-indexed columns

```
import pandas as pd
fish = [("Fish", lli) for lli in ["One", "Two"]]
dogs = [("Dog", lli) for lli in ["Three", "Four", "Five"]]
cats = [("Cat", lli) for lli in ["Three", "Four", "Five"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=["Blue", "Green", "Red"], columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(fish+dogs+cats))
```

-

df =

```
          Fish       Dog              Cat          
          One  Two   Three Four Five  Three Four Five
   Blue   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
   Green  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
   Red    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Now I would like to set the values of two columns at the same time, e.g.

```
df.loc[:, ('Dog', ['Four', 'Five'])] = 3.1
```

This leads to a KeyError saying

```
KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'
```

The problem can be "solved" by sorting the columns before setting the values using

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Now the issue is that I don't want to sort the columns as they are already sorted in a way that reflects the desired output.
Is there any way to set the values of multiple columns without sorting first?

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: This seems to be working in version `'1.0.0'`

Comment: For me working nice, I think is necessary upgade pandas

Comment: I'm on 0.19.1 and can't upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It working nice in last version of pandas.

If not possible upgrade pandas is possible select levels by masks created by [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) and [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) and set values like:

```
m1 = df.columns.get_level_values(0) == 'Dog'
m2 = df.columns.get_level_values(1).isin(['Four','Five'])

df.loc[:, m1 & m2] = 3.1
print (df)
      Fish        Dog             Cat          
       One  Two Three Four Five Three Four Five
Blue   NaN  NaN   NaN  3.1  3.1   NaN  NaN  NaN
Green  NaN  NaN   NaN  3.1  3.1   NaN  NaN  NaN
Red    NaN  NaN   NaN  3.1  3.1   NaN  NaN  NaN
```